# Fetching data through HTTP and caching JSON result in a file

Tags: python, json, error-handling, http, cache

The task is to fetch some JSON data from an API with a GET request. If the location is not available for any reason, read a cache file. Otherwise write the cache file for future use.

The following function works but it is clumsy due to:

- The nested `try`/`except`, which is difficult to read
- It's difficult to figure out what the error is (I am catching both `HTTPError` and the `JSONDecodeError` to avoid further nesting
- I don't dare to use a context manager for opening the file (`with`) due to a further nesting level within a `try`/`except` clause

Have you got any ideas for improvement?

```
def fetch_list(location=MY_LOCATION, cache_file=CACHE_FILE):
    """Goes to the default location and returns
    a python list
    """
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    try:
        r = http.request("GET",
                         location)
        raw_data = r.data.decode("utf-8")
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
    except (urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError, JSONDecodeError):
        logger.error("Cannot access Intranet List Location - fetching cache")
        try:
            data = json.loads(open(cache_file).readlines())
        except (IOError, JSONDecodeError):
            logger.error("Cache File not found or broken")
            raise
    else:
        with open(cache_file, "w") as f:
            f.write(raw_data)

    return data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `logger` object is derived from the [`logging` module](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/logging#logging.exception), use the `logger.exception` which'll log the traceback information as well. The docs (linked above) also specify this behaviour:

> Exception info is added to the logging message. This function should
>   only be called from an exception handler.

You can avoid nesting try-except block by just `pass`ing in first exception and place the write to cache inside the first `try` block itself:

```
def fetch_list(location=MY_LOCATION, cache_file=CACHE_FILE):
    """Goes to the default location and returns a python list.
    """
    try:
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        request = http.request("GET", location)
        raw_data = request.data.decode("utf-8")
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        with open(cache_file, "w") as cache:
            cache.write(raw_data)
        return data
    except (urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError, JSONDecodeError) as exc:
        logger.exception("Cannot access Intranet List Location - fetching cache")
    try:
        data = json.loads(open(cache_file).readlines())
        return data
    except (IOError, JSONDecodeError):
        logger.exception("Cache File not found or broken")
        raise
```

Comment: Isn't the `pass` superfluous?

Comment: @200_success yes, with the logger statement. The suggestion for `pass` was a generic one.

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks, do you have any idea about the duplicate catching of the `JSONDecodeError`?

Comment: @ProfHase85 You can skip decoding in the request section, and set `raw_data = open(cache_file).readlines()`. Do the `json.loads` once only. But that'd increase complexity imo.

Answer (score 1):

## Handle exceptions selectively

Currently you put all exception-throwing code into one big `try`-block:

```
try:
    r = http.request("GET",
                     location)
    raw_data = r.data.decode("utf-8")
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
except (urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError, JSONDecodeError):
```

On first glance it is not visible, that there might be a `UnicodeDecodeError`, which you are *not* catching (intentionally?).
It might increase readability to handle the possible exceptions of one statement at a time.

## Separate your concerns

The retrieval of the data from the Web-API and the caching of it seem to be two separate concerns to me, which should be handled by separate functions.
A decorator might be a fitting solution here.

## Handle unavailable endpoint value as error

A non-available value from the Web-API can thus be handled through a specific exception by the decorator

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from functools import wraps
from json import JSONDecodeError, dump, load, loads
from logging import getLogger
from urllib3 import PoolManager
from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError


LOCATION = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/'
CACHE = '/home/neumann/cache.json'
LOGGER = getLogger('MyLogger')


class DataNotRetrievable(Exception):
    """Indicates that the required data was not retrievable
    from the endpoint and a cached value is required.
    """

    pass


def json_cache(filename):
    """Chaches return value of the wrapped funtion to the respective file."""

    def decorator(function):
        """Actual decorator."""

        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """Wraps the decorated function."""
            try:
                json = function(*args, **kwargs)
            except DataNotRetrievable:
                LOGGER.exception('Could not retrieve data from website.')

                with open(filename, 'r') as cache:
                    return load(cache)

            with open(filename, 'w') as cache:
                dump(json, cache)

            return json

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@json_cache(CACHE)
def fetch_list(location=LOCATION):
    """Goes to the default location and returns a python list."""

    pmgr = PoolManager()

    try:
        response = pmgr.request("GET", location)
    except HTTPError:
        raise DataNotRetrievable()

    try:
        text = response.data.decode()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        raise DataNotRetrievable()

    try:
        return loads(text)
    except JSONDecodeError:
        raise DataNotRetrievable()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fetch_list())
```